# How to change default behavior of prop shortcut in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When we use the prop shortcut to generate a property, it generates it as an int.
However, in most of the cases, I use string properties. Is there any way I can change the default behavior of this shortcut to generate string properties?

Comment: Resharper generates public TYPE Type { get; set; }, I actually searched myself if you can override this, but couldn't find so looking forward to see if someone can answer

Comment: FYI: [MSDN doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165394.aspx) how to create  your own Snippet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I wrote my own snippets for custom behavior like that. like `props` for string etc.

If you open up `Code Snippet Manager` in Visual studio it will show you the location of the snippet file, which is editable. The location varies based on the version if VS you are using.

On VS2013 it showed the following path for `prop` for c#

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC#\Snippets\1033\Visual C#/prop.snippet`

I am then able to open it a text editor and customize the file as needed.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>prop</Title>
            <Shortcut>prop</Shortcut>
            <Description>Code snippet for an automatically implemented property
Language Version: C# 3.0 or higher</Description>
            <Author>Microsoft Corporation</Author>
            <SnippetTypes>
                <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
            </SnippetTypes>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Declarations>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>type</ID>
                    <ToolTip>Property type</ToolTip>
                    <Default>string</Default>
                </Literal>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>property</ID>
                    <ToolTip>Property name</ToolTip>
                    <Default>MyProperty</Default>
                </Literal>
            </Declarations>
            <Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[public $type$ $property$ { get; set; }$end$]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

Note how the above was changed to `string` for default type

Comment: I know two people have upvoted for this answer and it looks like it should work. But for some reason unknown, it is not working for me in VS 2017.
I edited prop.snippet but it is still showing int. I even restarted VS

Comment: @CuriousNewbie what is not working. Did you find the snippet file and edit it?

Comment: Ok, my bad. The prop snippet was at two places. One under C:\ProgramFiles(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\...... And another under C:\ProgramFiles(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\.......
Changing at the former location didn't work, changing at latter did work. Marked answer as accepted

Comment: The problem with just overwriting the default snippet file is that when Visual Studio gets an update, it overwrites your changes again with the original snippet again!  My guess is it has a copy of the content of the original snippet in the installer that performs the update.